# What is the vector-diagram method of linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to find some information about the vector-diagram method of linear programming, but this seems that in my language this method has very different from English language name.
So, I was wondering, maybe someone can recognize this method?

Some of the main steps:

1. Calculate the normal vector (`N`) of the function and external normals (`n`).
2. Calculate `cos()=((N;n)/|n|)`
3. Write down equation of the plane.

I would really love to give you more, but that's all I have.

[Steps of the method in my native language (Ukrainian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FPx6.png)

Comment: Is this a method specific to 3-dimensional problems? I tried reading the Ukrainian, but I'm stuck on the first step, which I think tells me to put the problem in some kind of standard form (and I don't know which one).